# Make Android ListView smooth as Spotify, Ted, Twitter, etc

Tags: android, android-listview

I'm trying to find the best way to load images into a ListView in Android from URLs (specifically Facebook events and Facebook friend profile pics)

I have tried many different libraries including Shutterbug, webimageloader, the acclaimed [LazyList](https://github.com/thest1/LazyList) and can never get a completely smooth scrolling ListView like that of the friend's list in Spotify or the Ted talks app or the Twitter app's profile pic loading.

Can anyone point me in the right direction so I can get a smooth scrolling list?

My adapter's getView():

```
@Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        FriendView fView = null;
        if (convertView == null) {
            fView = new FriendView();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.friend_layout, parent,
                    false);
            fView.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.friendName);
            fView.name.setTypeface(tf);
            fView.pic = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.profilePic);
            convertView.setTag(fView);
        } else {
            fView = (FriendView) convertView.getTag();
        }
        fView.name.setText(nameEvents.get(position));
        HomeScreen.imageLoader.DisplayImage(graphBase + ids.get(position)
                + graphEndForPic, fView.pic);
        return convertView;
    }

static class FriendView {
        public TextView name;
        public ImageView pic;
    }
```

Things aren't too terrible, but the list is about 600 items, and all the images have different URLs. I can't really fling through it at all, because it will load all the images while scrolling and lags...

Comment: Have you checked that your list is scrolling smoothly without displaying images? Those libraries should have no big impact if they do it right

Comment: Can you post the method getView() of your adapter?

Comment: Edited it and added my getView(). The above still gitters when the image is being loaded into the list.

Comment: Does it get smooth if you remove the call to DisplayImage() but add a simple dummy call to ids.get(position) ? If not, good luck with Traceview.

Comment: post the rest of the adapter code

Comment: Yes it does get smooth when I make a simple dummy call to ids.get(position).

Comment: Still looking to make it better...

Comment: Which size are your images ?

Comment: Roughly 2-8kb per image.

Comment: If I fling past the ones that are loading and get into completely unloaded images, it'll get smoother, it's the flicker when they load into the listview that makes things choppy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the issue was with a SlidingMenu library that I was using (Similar to the one in Spotify) and the fix was to update it. The older version didn't remove the views when it was closed so there was 4-5 layers of GPU overdraw. Using the dev tools introduced in Jelly Bean helped me find this out.